# Ubuntu 13.10 without sound in flashvideos at Firefox/Chromiun

Tags: sound, firefox, 13.04, flash

Hey guys my new ubuntu is no sound when i play flash videos. 
But in my players sound is fine.

Any suggestion?

sorry for my bad english
cheers from brazil :)

Answer (score 3):

Giaco's answer didn't work for me.
I did all the following and after I rebooted it worked again, so not sure which one did the trick:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf => add this line at bottom: options snd-hda-intel model=auto
sudo pam-auth-update --force => tab to ok button and enter
```

Ref: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166214

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

It's for 13.04, but maybe it could work also for 13.10 ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.